# Chart and prop states

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I need to display a graph that is divided into years and months. At the beginning I created 12 props with months (the following code), 2 props over the years and created a schedule.

```
        this.state = {
            menu: [  //year
                {
                    key: 2018,
                    title: "2018",
                    opened: true,
                },
                {
                    key: 2019,
                    title: "2019",
                    opened: false
                }],
            active_menu: 2018, //key from opened (active) year
            info: [   //months with data
                {
                    key: 11,
                    title: 'December',
                    opened: true,
                    content: []
                },{
                    // other months
                }],
            active_month: 11 //key from opened (active) month
        }
```

Now there are difficulties ... in 2018, for example, the countdown of months begins from September to December, and in 2019 there is only January. Moreover, when I take the data for the schedule, I focus on the month selected by the user, substituting it in the query.

this would also be no problem if it were not for one thing: I don’t need to display elements that are not present in the year (for example, if the user chose the year 2019, I only need to show January)I would like to withdraw all months from September to December in 2018, and for 2019, display each month as soon as it ends (for example, February will appear only on March 1)

now I understand perfectly well that with the current implementation I can not implement the necessary functionality, but the understanding of how best to do this, too, does not come to me ... please help me with advice, I’m really stumped.

sorry for the long message, I had no one to ask for advice

Comment: Just to understand your question further let me ask a couple questions. 1. You want to choose specific months per year to be accessible in the `state`? 2. Will all years be consistent in a certain pattern or will it vary every year?

Comment: 1.Yes desirable
2. We plan to simply add each year to the end

Comment: Well I don't see why you can't just add the required months into the `state.info` array, and loop over it. It won't contain anything more than you give it. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Keno Clayton Sorry, please, that I ask a lot, but could you show it with an example. It sounds quite reasonable, maybe this is our way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should hopefully give you an idea as to how you'd want to structure your data.

Firstly, if your actual data isn't changing, you could put it into a regular `const` and refer to it later. But we'll continue with your existing pattern.

```
...
     active_menu: 2018, //key from opened (active) year
     info: [   //months with data
       {
         key: 11,
         title: 'December',
         opened: true,
         content: []
       },
       {
         // other months
       }
    ],
    active_month: 11 //key from opened (active) month
```

We can focus entirely on the state relating to your months. Just populate `this.state.info` with the months that you actually need, and you'll be able to later map over them.

E.g.

```
class sampleComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(index) {
    let copy = [...this.state.info]; //create local copy of state array
    let active = copy[index].key;
    this.setState({active_month: active});
  }


  render() {
    const buttons = this.state.info.map((month, index) => 
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(index)} key={month.key}/>
    );

    return (
      //return anything else here
      {buttons}
    )
  }
}
```

You'd only render buttons that connect directly to your state and would only handle the months you have in the state. Hope this helps to answer your question.